# How can I disable Internet Explorer 'This website has been reported as unsafe'

Tags: internet-explorer

I want need to disable 'This website has been reported as unsafe' page on Internet Explorer, so I can open phishing webpages for my testing.

Chrome and Firefox has the same page but can be easily removed from the settings of the browser.

I can't find the solution for Internet Explorer. Does anyone know how to disable this feature in IE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as it's a general use question rather than one about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Solution: on IE
Settings -> Safety -> Turn off SmartScreen filter

Comment: Here, I am not sure what kind of testing you are doing by accessing phishing web pages but it is not recommended to turn off smart screen filter. It is there to protect user from unsafe contents from internet. you can get more information by visiting this link. https://feedback.smartscreen.microsoft.com/smartscreenfaq.aspx